# run only doctests from python nose

Tags: python, nose, nosetests

Is there a way to run only doctests using Python Nose (nosetests)? . I do not want to run any unittests but only and only the doctests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that effect ignoring all regular test files.
This can be done easily using the `-I` or `--ignore-files` options and a regex like `.*\.py`.

An other way could be to save the doctests in a separate directory and launch nose on that.

---

In newer versions of nose this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: at least for nose-1.3.6 this does not work (it executes nothing at all, which makes sense, since you're ignoring all source files)

Comment: @marscher It worked back then. If you have a different solution put it in an answer. I'll add a note about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with newer versions of `nose`, but I haven't tested it on nested modules.

```
echo 'import '"$PACKAGE"', inspect; print("\n".join(x[0] for x in inspect.getmembers('"$PACKAGE"', inspect.ismodule)))' | python | xargs -L 1 --replace echo "$PACKAGE.{}" | nose $(cat) --with-doctest
```

If you know of an easier way to extract the list of modules to doctest (perhaps using nose?), then that's all the first part is really doing.