# Nose does not run doctests from imported modules

Tags: python, nose, doctest

I have a project with a structure like that :

```
my_project_with_tests/
  project/
    __init__.py
    module.py
  test/
    test.py
```

`module.py` contains two `doctest`'ed functions:

```
def foo():
  """
  >>> foo()
  1
  """
  return 1

def test_foo_doctest():
    """
    >>> module.foo()
    1
    """
    pass


def bar():
  """
  >>> bar()
  """
  return 1
```

`test.py` contains the necessary bits to run tests:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path = [os.path.abspath("../project")] + sys.path


import module


def test_foo():
    assert module.foo() == 1


def test_bar():
    assert module.bar() == 1
```

I'm currently running my tests using `nose` with

```
nosetests                   \
    --all-modules           \
    --traverse-namespace    \
    --with-coverage         \
    --cover-tests           \
    --with-doctest          \
    --where test/
```

However, it does not run `doctests` from my `project` sources directory (but `doctests` from the test directory are ok, since `test_foo_doctest` passes).

1. Is this the good way to call `nose` ?
2. How can I run `doctests` from the `project` directory

   - using `nose`
   - without changing the directory structure
   - without running tests in the `project` directory

Comment: I'm confused.  You don't want to run tests in the project directory, but you want to run the doctests in module.py, which are in the project directory.

Comment: Yep. I want to mimic the `cover` plugin from nose: When running tests, it computes the coverage of tests of these modules. Likewise, I would like to run the doctests of modules imported by the tests (or all modules in the `project` directory in fact).

Comment: Your question and comments on the below answer and ambiguous - you state that you want to run tests in `project` and also don't want to run them.  Can you clarify your question by making the two "project" directory names in your example unique?

Comment: Oh, ok :-) Edited to remove ambiguities.

Comment: Your nose doesn't run? Sounds like a good thing to me...

Comment: Still a little confusing on first read, but seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819489/run-only-doctests-from-python-nose

Answer (score 2):

1. That's a good way to call nose, but there's a small problem that prevents your doctests from running. See #2
2. Change `--where test/` to `--where .`  assuming you run the command from `project/project`.  That way nose will see the doctests.  Right now it's only looking in test/

Comment: But it will not run tests in the `test/` directory ? And it will try to run the ones in `project/`...

Comment: This will runs tests in all directories in project/project/ and below.  So it will run tests in project/project/module.py, project/project/test/tests.py, and if you have project/project/moretests/tests.py, it will run those as well

Comment: If you also need to exclude moretests/tests.py, you can use the [nose-exclude plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-exclude)

Comment: Ok, I edited the question since I don't want to change the directory structure, and I don't want to run tests in the `project` directory.